# How do I duplicate a custom code block in Scratch?

Tags: mit-scratch

I've got a custom code block that I've written in Scratch:

[image: Scratch Decimal to Binary]

I want to duplicate my code block so that I can have a second version that is slightly different instead of having to create a whole new block from scratch manually.

Is it possible to duplicate any of "My Blocks"?

Comment: Duplicating the 'body' of the custom block is easy and would already save you a lot of work. You'd only have to create a new 'head' manually. Would that be acceptable to you?

Comment: @RuudHelderman Ah. Yes. That's useful. That's perfect. Thanks. You're welcome to post an answer to that. It's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: How "slightly" is your new block different from the original? I would strongly suggest to NOT duplicate a block, but add a parameter and implement that variation within one block.

Comment: @VladFeinstein Good advice. In fact, I don't recall ever feeling the need to duplicate a custom block _within the same sprite_ (though across sprites, I consider it common practice). However, an additional parameter to change the behavior of a custom block may lead to overly complex code (typically with too many if-then-else blocks); Scratch has no [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), [interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(object-oriented_programming)) or [homoiconicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicating the 'body' of the custom block is easy and would already save you a lot of work. You'd only have to create a new 'head' manually.

Steps to take:

- Right-click on the first block underneath the original custom block's hat block (in your case: the block "set binary to 0").
- From the context menu, select 'Duplicate'. This will duplicate the block and everything below it, i.e. everything except the hat block.
- Create a new custom block. Make sure it has the same parameters as the original custom block.
- Drag and drop the duplicated blocks under the new custom hat block.

---

**Edit:**
There's actually a way to duplicate both head and body.
It makes use of the fact that dragging a block to another sprite will duplicate it.
Obviously it does demand you to rename the duplicate; having two custom blocks with the same name within the same sprite is a very bad idea.

As you may have guessed, your project needs at least two sprites to perform this trick.
If your project only has one sprite, then just create a temporary dummy sprite, and delete it when done.

Steps:

- Go to the code of the sprite with the custom block you'd like to duplicate; let's call this sprite A.
- Drag the custom block (the entire script) to the panel at the bottom right of the project editor, and drop it on sprite B.
- Go to the code of sprite B. Notice a copy of the custom block is present there.
- Rename the custom block (to avoid a conflict with the original custom block).
- Drag the custom block back to sprite A.
- Delete the custom block from sprite B (or delete the entire sprite if it was just a dummy).
- Go to the code of sprite A. Notice both custom blocks are present there. If you see only one, drag it aside a bit; it may be overlapping and hiding the original custom block.